# Overlay a popover carrying a widget automatically in WordPress?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, overlay

http://many-wounds.com/ - this is the blog, it runs on wordpress.

I'm using a genesis theme, it comes with a separate section in the widgets area called, "Offscreen Content", and in it I can drag any widget. As is clear I wanted that widget to be the one that displays my email opt-in form. And it looks good enough, in my opinion.

[Overlay Widget section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YSc9.png)

However, this overlay can only be launched by manually clicking on a button on the top left hand corner.

If a user has been reading my blog for sometime, is it not possible for this overlay to launch automatically?

In other words how can this overlay be triggered automatically after sometime.

And it's not important that use just the default overlay thing. I can use any other overlay method so long as it can embed other plugins in itself.

Or can I do it by using hooks?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use jQuery and trigger the click event toggle button since you are already utilizing jQuery.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    jQuery('.offscreen-content-toggle').first().trigger('click');
}, 10000);
```

Comment: Thank You so much! Can I use any cookie mechanism so that it only shows up once for a visitor?

Comment: Adding another answer for that.

Comment: The better solution in my experience for this case is using localStorage and set a custom variable instead of cookie.

Comment: ok! you're very smart. thanks! I'm absolutely a noob when it comes to jquery, if you could write a code for that, it would be a great, great help or perhaps just broadly outline the steps.

Comment: No jQuery pure vanilla JS. Try the following link, the code should be simple as copy paste.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage